# Recent spam for sport blog

Tags: discussion

Recently, there has been a surge of spam posts for a sport blog, broadcasting illegal streaming. Although such posts have always been correctly flagged as spam and the corresponding accounts destroyed by the moderators, an extra action to help prevent this kind of posts is [to report the blog to blogspot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192837). 
I've done it, but I guess the more people reporting it, the more likely it is that google takes action. I won't put the link of the blog here, but next time a similar post arises, please keep it in mind!

Comment: As a quick update: the blog in question has now been removed from blogspot, so it works!

Comment: [Here's a direct link to the Blogspot reporting page.](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/42577?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for the link to my post :-)